# How to assign multiple string values into a variable in shell scripts?

Tags: shell, command, echo

I'm trying to loop a text file changing the number and the hole string is store into a shell variable, to print it latter

I've tried echo the string an the integer (number from the loop) using ">>"

```
#!/bin/bash
a=0
while [ "$a" -lt 4 ]
do
    echo '<div name="block-'${a}'">' >> $sub_main
    ((a++))
done
echo "done"
echo $sub_main
```

The output from the script should be:

```
<div name="block-0">
<div name="block-1">
<div name="block-2">
<div name="block-3">
```

Comment: Do you care about putting it in a variable? You could just remove the `>> $sub_main` and `echo $sub_main`, and then your script will have the expected output

Answer (score 1):

`>>` appends the out putto a file. If you want to append to a variable you can use an assignment with the variable to append to at the beginning of the right value.

```
a=0;
sub_main="";
while [ "${a}" -lt 4 ]; do
  sub_main="${sub_main}\n<div name=\"block-${a}\">";
  ((a++));
done;
echo "done";
echo "${sub_main}";
```

Or, if the appending to the file was intended, you can simply use `cat` instead of `echo`, to output the file's contents.

I.e. replace

```
echo $sub_main
```

with:

```
cat "${sub_main}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use command substitution to capture the output into a variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
sub_main=$(
    for (( a = 0; a < 4; a++ )); do
        printf '<div name="block-%d">\n' "$a"
    done
)
# ... do other stuff ...
echo "$sub_main"
```

Or you might want to use a function to defer execution until later:

```
#!/bin/bash
sub_main() {
    for (( a = 0; a < 4; a++ )); do
        printf '<div name="block-%d">\n' "$a"
    done
}
# ... do other stuff ...
sub_main
```